# Add users to the site collection administrator group through code

Tags: development

You can add users to the site collection administrators group through 
Site Actions ->Site Collection Administrators (and add users)

But how can you do this through code?
What is the grpName?

web.EnsureUser(User.LoginName);
web.SiteGroups[grpName].AddUser(@User.LoginName, string.Empty, LookupValue, string.Empty);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the SPUser object for a user in a Site Collection and update the [IsSiteAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.issiteadmin.aspx) property.

```
function makeUserSiteCollectionAdmin(SPUser user)
{
    user.IsSiteAdmin = true;
    user.Update();
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the account running the code (i.e. if in a webpart) needs permissions to make this change so a SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges block might be required.